# UIButton reference from UIMenuElement

Tags: swift, uibutton, uimenuitem

I have four UIButton's and each has an associated UIPopUpMenu.  Each UIMenuElement has the same action and menu list across all four UIButtons's.  My selector essentially does the same action, but saves the data into an Array based on which UIButton was originally selected to get to the UIMenu.

This is my action definition: @IBAction func changeName (sender: UIMenuElement) { }

If I try to use "sender: UIButton" instead, I get a fatal error.  However, I can't seem to find out how to get a reference to the UIButton touched when using the "sender: UIMenuElement".  I need the Tag from that button to determine where to save the information.

Comment: Are you doing this from the storyboard? I would just programmatically do this and use `UIAction`s as the menu elements. You can just pass them a closure and the closure can capture the button.

Comment: I guess that's the problem.  Whether I am doing it from Storyboard (via a selector defined there) or doing it programmatically as you suggest, I'm not sure how to access the tag attribute of the UIButton.

Comment: I did end up doing it programmatically with UIAction (instead of UICommand).  Since I was updating the menu list based on all the available names anyway, I just added in the tag number into the handler dynamically while creating the menu for each button in viewDidLoad.  So, in the end, it works without really any more work.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

See my comment for my solution.  Happy to share more details if anyone is curious. Thanks.

```
playerMenu.append(UIAction(title: allPlayers[i], handler: {_ in self.changeName(theTag: j)}))
```

Where `allPlayers` is my list of the player names, `i` is from the for..next adding each name to the menu, and `j` is from the for..next adding the menu to each button.